# Including a github library to my CLion Cpp project

Tags: cmake, clion

I had a small cpp project that I was making on a Windows machine, it had an external library off of [GitHub](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). I am now trying to copy this project to my M1 Mac machine and run it in CLion. So far it has been unsuccessful.

I'm obviously a complete novice, so any help would be appreciated.

I have Homebrew, CMake installed.
I have also run `brew install nlohmann-json` in terminal.

I've tried:

---

1. 

main.cpp

```
#include "json.hpp"
```

CMakeListst.txt:
add_executable(main main.cpp json.hpp)

json.hpp file from github is in the project directory.

---

I've read that I only need json.hpp in project directory for this to work, but I still get errors that some files are missing, in this case 'nlohmann/adl_serializer.hpp'

Comment: The actual release of "json.hpp" does not depend on any other "nlohmann..." headers. I think you took the file from the source tree instead of taking the "release" from the sidebar. They're totally different files named "json.hpp"!

Comment: @Romen This issue took me hours, I was at my wits end, and it turns out I copy-pasted the wrong json.hpp file to the project directory :) I feel so dumb right now, THANK YOU! You are a lifesaver!